# spark generic case class to structtype

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics

I want to achieve somethign similar to http://benfradet.github.io/blog/2017/06/14/Deriving-Spark-Dataframe-schemas-with-Shapeless but without shapeless

```
 def generateStructTypeFromCaseClass[T <: Product](): StructType =
    ScalaReflection.schemaFor[T].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

fails to compile with:

```
No TypeTag available for T
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add and implicit `TypeTag[T]` parameter to your method as follows:

```
 def generateStructTypeFromCaseClass[T <: Product]()(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): StructType =
   ScalaReflection.schemaFor[T].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

This parameter will be automatically filled by the compiler. See [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) for details.